# How to remove charging icon from WatchKit Simulator?

Tags: ios, watchkit, xcode-6.2

Would like to see if my app name will fit when the watch isn't charging, which I'm assuming wont be there when in use.
See image: https://i.stack.imgur.com/WRGDe.jpg

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Short answer is you can't.

However, during transitions from controller to controller, or when reloading root controllers etc., the entire status will only display the title, and then the status bar will animate back to it's original state.

You may be able to setup a test using the same title across multiple controllers to see make an educated guess as to what it's going to look like.